# Proxy error while deploying Spring boot app on Jelastic

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, proxy, jelastic

I am trying to deploy simple Spring Boot app on Jelastic. So I have created environment with Java 8, Postgres 9.5, Apache 2.4, deployed **war**-file and nothing works.

I receive the following error:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an
> upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request GET
> /localize/. Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
> Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Server at node30... Port 80

It might be for the following reason: my server configurated on port 5555. However, I don't see any options that would tell Jelastic about the neccesary port.

Comment: Which application server are you deploying to + do you have public IP (if yes on which node)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At this point the service says that even can't find the page. Also I found out that free period is only 14 days + I didn't find easy way to copy my Postgres data to the service. So for me is better to look at the other cloud services.

Comment: If your goal is free hosting then yes Jelastic is not the ideal option. But if you want help to host your project, I'll be happy to help you set things up.

Comment: Damien, it would be great if you could give me some advices. It is my first step to host in clouds. I would create, if you don't mind, a new question about hosting on Jelastic, so that others could go through the steps. I'll give the link here when I create new question. It might be tomorrow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok no problem. I think once you get started Jelastic will be the best option for you; most alternatives require you to look after the server too, which is definitely not a good option for your first cloud hosting (I would argue not a good option ever... but I'm biased about that).

Comment: Damien, I have created a new question. The link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328762/how-to-host-spring-boot-application-with-postgresql-on-jelastic